# Losing a node reference? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom

So I have this JS code :

```
var pElt = document.createElement("p");
var aElt = document.createElement("a");
aElt.textContent = "Text";
aElt.href = "#";
pElt.appendChild(aElt);

aElt.style.color = "red";
pElt.innerHTML += "<span> and more text</span>";
//aElt.style.color = "red";

document.getElementById("content").appendChild(pElt);

console.log(aElt); // always show the red attribute
```

There's probably some answer around here, but I cannot even describe the problem ; so I went with "losing node reference", even though it's not what happens here. (edit: in fact, that's what happens here, silly :))

So... Please try the code as it is. It works, the link is red, everyone is happy. Now comment the "aElt.style.color = "red";" line, then uncomment the other one, two lines below.

...
It does not work, the link still appear in black. What I thought is that the pointer linked to my node was either not valid anymore or the aElt was moved to a different memory address. But when I type "console.log(aElt)", it outputs the node correctly (well... I think it does), so I don't get why I can't access it after the .innerHTML change.

What interests me is what happens under the hood :)

Thanks!

---

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Question!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you overwrite the content of the `<p>` element by setting it's `innerHTML`, you're effectively turning the `<a>` back into HTML *text*, appending the `<span>` (as text), and then recreating *new* DOM nodes in the `<p>`.  Your old reference still refers to the original `<a>` you created.

You could instead create that `<span>` the same way you created the `<a>`, and append that node to the `<p>` instead of overwriting `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. .innerHTML is definitely not my friend :)